# Python shuffling only one parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, shuffle

I have a python list which I can sort easily:

```
l2 = sorted(l1, key=lambda k: k["id"])
print l2
```

which prints:

```
[ {'id': '02', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '02', 'time': 'm24' },  {'id': '05', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm12' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm24' }, {'id': '09', 'time': 'm12' }]
```

However I'd like now to use `shuffle`, to shuffle this list only based on the `id` key, I'd like to preserve *relative order* on the `time` key. Is there a way to do this ?

by relative order, I meant that original sorting by key `time` is preserved. Eg a possible solution would be:

```
[ {'id': '09', 'time': 'm12' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm12' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm24' }, {'id': '02', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '02', 'time': 'm24' }]
```

One can check that items are sorted partially by key `time` for each `id`.

Comment: Consider change of tour current data structures. For now you have isolated dictionaires. Easiest way to shuffle them as you want is to redesign them into eg. tuples, which contains another tuples and then try to shuffle them.

Comment: create list of `id`'s, `shuffle` it and write `id`'s back in new places.

Comment: What does "I'd like to preserve invariance" mean. Do you want to keep the data order and change the ids ?

Comment: Ok, so your question isn't clear on what you want/need. you should've explained that you wanted to shuffle by 'groups' with the same id, and keep the order of each group. In `l2` you have the groups `02`, `05` and `09` and that's what you want to shuffle.

Comment: I've fixed the question, using the proper wording `relative order`, from the `stable sort` wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs, I believe a working solution is:

```
import random
# l2 is sorted totally:
l2 =[ {'id': '02', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '02', 'time': 'm24' },  {'id': '05', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm12' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm24' }, {'id': '09', 'time': 'm12' }]
idss = set([i['id'] for i in l2])
ids = list(idss)

random.shuffle(ids)
l3 = []

for i in ids:
    for j in l2:
        if i == j['id']:
            # order by `time` is implicit
            l3.append(j)
print l3
```

Nothing very fantastic as I need to loop over the whole array `l2` everytime, but code is readable.

Comment: Does this mean you just wanted to sort the 'groups' of items? Keep all items with the same 'id' together?

Comment: Then your question is really not clear. I'll edit my post (again)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
from random import shuffle

l2 = [ {'id': '02', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '02', 'time': 'm24' },  {'id': '05', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm12' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm24' }, {'id': '09', 'time': 'm12' }]
print(l2)

keys = [item['id'] for item in l2]
shuffle(keys)

for n in range(len(keys)):
    l2[n]['id'] = keys[n]

print(l2)
```

It prints:

```
>>> [{'id': '02', 'time': 'bl'}, {'id': '02', 'time': 'm24'}, {'id': '05', 'time': 'bl'}, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm12'}, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm24'}, {'id': '09', 'time': 'm12'}]
>>> [{'id': '02', 'time': 'bl'}, {'id': '09', 'time': 'm24'}, {'id': '05', 'time': 'bl'}, {'id': '02', 'time': 'm12'}, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm24'}, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm12'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want is to keep the data in groups and then shuffle the groups.

```
ids = list(set([id['id'] for id in l2]))
random.shuffle(ids)

l3 =[]
for id in ids:
    l3.extend([item for item in l2 if item['id']==id])
```

---

From what I understood, you want to shuffle the items in your list but keeping the order of the `time` values for similar ids.

```
l2 = [ {'id': '02', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '02', 'time': 'm24' },  {'id': '05', 'time': 'bl' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm12' }, {'id': '05', 'time': 'm24' }, {'id': '09', 'time': 'm12' }]
import random
ids = [id['id'] for id in l2]
random.shuffle(ids)
d = dict()
for id in set(ids):
    d[id] = [item for item in l2 if item['id'] == id]

l3 = []
for id in ids:
    l3.append(d[id].pop(0))
```

In my case it printed:

```
print ids
>>['05', '09', '02', '02', '05', '05']

print l2
>>[{'id': '02', 'time': 'bl'},
   {'id': '02', 'time': 'm24'},
   {'id': '05', 'time': 'bl'},
   {'id': '05', 'time': 'm12'},
   {'id': '05', 'time': 'm24'},
   {'id': '09', 'time': 'm12'}]

print l3
>>[{'id': '05', 'time': 'bl'},
   {'id': '09', 'time': 'm12'},
   {'id': '02', 'time': 'bl'},
   {'id': '02', 'time': 'm24'},
   {'id': '05', 'time': 'm12'},
   {'id': '05', 'time': 'm24'}]
```

You could also use a generator instead of list comprehension when building the lists in the dictionary:

```
for id in set(ids):
    d[id] = (c for c in l2 if c['id'] == id)
for id in ids:
    l3.append(next(d[id]))
```

Comment: this will *not* be ordered partially by key `time`

Comment: So you want to shuffle but keep the order in the cases where two ids are the same?

Comment: Your comment is accurate, but your code does not seems to work. `l2` should group by `id` and order by `time`

Comment: I still don't get what you want. You want to shuffle the ids, but keep the sorting of the original list, right? I'll edit and reread.